# Apache and PHP security, limiting subdomains

Tags: php, security, apache

I'm just curious if there's a way to disable things like `shell_exec()` using the .htaccess file or something, not globally, but only for specific subdomains or directories (possibly disable `fopen()` on files above the subdir). It occurred to me that on one of my shared hosts where I'm sharing subdomain space with a friend he could use PHP to get a look at directories outside his own.

Perhaps I could use mod_rewrite and send any hit anywhere through a PHP script that disables certain things before forwarding the request to where it was going? Would this work, and would it incur a significant performance penalty?

Comment: Your list of functions will need to be pretty big though. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions/3451100 and it won't stop me doing this:  $y = str_replace('z', 'e', 'zxzc'); $y("malicious code");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it programmatically:

`ini_set('disable_functions', 'fopen,shell_exec');`

or in `.htaccess`:

`php_value disable_functions fopen,shell_exec`

There shouldn't be any performance degradation. I doubt you'll be changing the settings repeatedly inside a `for()`, `while()` or `foreach()` loop.

Comment: I'd suggest using `php_admin_value` instead of `php_value`, so that the parameters are not overrideable via an .htaccess. See: [configuration.changes.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Comment: @lucaferrario Why would anyone in their right mind override something in that same file?

Comment: A malicious software (attacked joomla or wordpress) could write a new .htaccess and override settings... Or simply, if you are a service provider, one of your customers could...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a .htaccess file:

http://www.askapache.com/php/custom-phpini-tips-and-tricks.html#m0-askapache12

Answer (score 0):

I believe those things need to be changed in the php.ini file.  Some host allow you to have multiple php.ini files within the files structure.  If you are on a shared hosting environment then you probably will have one php.ini file for all shared accounts.  Host realize this is a problem so they allow you to have your own within your home directory for sub directory... check with your host.