# How to restrict opendir from going past root folder?

Tags: php, apache, restrict, opendir

I am trying to simulate shared hosting on my local server by blocking off the root directory.

I've tried:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/root">
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

in `httpd.conf` (restarted Apache)

and

```
Options -Indexes
```

in the `.htaccess` of `htdocs`.

**What do I need to do to restrict `opendir` from accessing beyond this folder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `open_basedir` in the config file

[open_basedir - how to set for specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291185/open-basedir-how-to-set-for-specific-directory)

Comment: aha! the examples I found excluded the path in quotes. Works like a charm now, thanks.