# PHP Warning: include_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, warnings, restriction, open-basedir

I have migrated a site from one host to another, on this site there is a crm working or at least used to work. Since the migration was done the link to the crm responded with error500-internal server error and I contacted the host in order to check it. They said they fixed it and now it shows me the following

> PHP Warning:  include_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/crm/includes/adodbtime/adodb-time.inc.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (G:/PleskVhosts//mysite.com\;C:\Windows\Temp) in G:\PleskVhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs\crm\filefunc.inc.php on line 229
>
> PHP Warning:  include_once(/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/crm/includes/adodbtime/adodb-time.inc.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in G:\PleskVhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs\crm\filefunc.inc.php on line 229
>
> PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/crm/includes/adodbtime/adodb-time.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='G:\PleskVhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs/htdocs') in G:\PleskVhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs\crm\filefunc.inc.php on line 229
>
> PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/crm/core/lib/functions.lib.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (G:/PleskVhosts//mysite.com\;C:\Windows\Temp) in G:\PleskVhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs\crm\filefunc.inc.php on line 231

I'm using plesk panel and I'm really new to this. The solutions I came up with require changes to the php.ini file that I have no access to. Before I contact the host again I thought I would ask here first.

I'm showing the code on those lines to if it is a bit of help:

```
if (! defined('ADODB_DATE_VERSION')) include_once ADODB_PATH.'adodb-time.inc.php';

if (! file_exists(DOL_DOCUMENT_ROOT ."/core/lib/functions.lib.php"))
```

Comment: It looks like your new host doesn't allow PHP to read from the directory you are currently trying to use. See here for a previous, more detailed, answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the directory to the allowed paths of your server.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291185/open-basedir-how-to-set-for-specific-directory) post is well explanatory.

Aditionally if you are using Plesk, probably the easiest way to set this path is to set it through php.ini on the root directory of your application.

`open_basedir = /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/crm/includes/adodbtime`