# Store to file using PHP

Tags: php, store, fwrite

I have a text file in my system named "flow.txt". It is stores in my Documents folder. I want to write into this file using php. I have used following code to do this but no changes are observed in the file. It always show "Couldn't open $fp for writing!" .

```
 $fp = fopen('~/Documents/flow.txt', 'a') or die("Couldn't open $fp for writing!");
 fwrite($fp, print_r($arr, true));
 fclose($fp);
```

And also tried  file_put_contents() function. But, it too didn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your path to that file is wrong. nothing else

Comment: Then what it should be ? I also tried 'home/anurag/Documents/flow.txt'

Comment: Have you tried '/home/anurag/Documents/flow.txt' ' with the leading slash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write into a file in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768894/how-to-write-into-a-file-in-php)

Comment: define path of `flow.txt` and your current file

Comment: @SergeyNazarenko yes I tried it also.

Comment: Maybe, you have no permissions to create the file or to write into the file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest three points:

1. File path: Make sure the path is correct. Probably go to the folder Documents and command `pwd` to confirm it.
2. Permission: To avoid possibility of different web server's user/group, suggest testing with permission 777 to check it: `chmod 777 flow.txt` in folder Documents and `chmod 777 Documents` in home. If it is, change back the permissions and modify the web server's (httpd?) User/Group in the configuration file.
3. open_basedir: Check this setting referring to [open_basedir - how to set for specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291185/open-basedir-how-to-set-for-specific-directory).

Hope it helps.