# PHP rename() permission denied via Apache (SELinux related)

Tags: php, apache, selinux

I have a simple script that outputs `Permission denied` warning in the browser:

```
rename('/opt/web/test.tmp', '/opt/web/test.tmp1')
```

Script path is `/opt/web/test_rename.php`

`/opt/`, `/opt/web/` and `/opt/web/test_rename.php` are 777 and have `apache` owner / group.

`httpd` process owner is `apache`

`test.tmp` is 777 and have `apache` owner as well

It works fine with cli.

What else could I do to make it work via apache?

Comment: Hi, which rights have file /opt/web/test.tmp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open\_basedir - how to set for specific directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291185/open-basedir-how-to-set-for-specific-directory)

Comment: this may helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/move-uploaded-file-gives-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-after

Comment: @vonOak test.tmp is 777 apache

Comment: @Brian it looks like an unrelated issue...

Comment: @KrisRoofe it doesn't help :( the owner of the process is `apache`, i've checked it by `ps aux | grep httpd` so the file 100% should be accessable by the process

Comment: also `fopen` and `fwrite` work fine by apache, unlike `rename`

Comment: I even can `unlink` it and create with different name by `fopen`. `mkdir` also works. wtf...

Comment: `copy` + `unlink` work fine as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with SELinux. It can block php `rename` function.

I've found the answer here: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-111081.html

*On the Fedora Core 3 Linux distribution, you may get a "failed to open stream: Permission denied in ..." message. In fact changing the permission of the directory will not work (even if you set to 0777).*

*It is because of the new SELinux kernel that allow apache user to write only in /tmp dir (I think). In order to solve the problem you must to disable the SELinux (at least for apache service) to allow the server to write in other directories. To do that, run the `system-config-securitylevel` app and disable the SE to apache service. Reboot your system and continue your work.*