# PHP Configuration Module Security Considerations

Tags: php, security, nginx

What are the modules in a PHP configuration that are considered higher risk and should be avoided or additional security steps should be considered when implementing? (All Apache/Nginx/Infrastructure Considerations aside)

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about your php configuration then you should run [PHPSecInfo](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/).  If you are worried about sensitive php functionality you should take a look at [Exploitable PHP Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions/3697776#3697776).

Comment: +1 Great list there Rook, and Suhosin is indeed a nice addition.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rook. However, I will say that you can't really say which modules are riskier than other. Take a look at their documentation. Search google for "modulename bugs", "modulename exploits", etc. Most of the answers you get here would be opinion. Try to get the information you need from the sources.