# un-exploitable php functions (whitelist)

Tags: php, smarty, exploit

Does anyone have a prepared whitelist of **as many as possible** secure / unexploitable PHP functions?

I am building a web application where user enters the Smarty template (Smarty version 3). Application runs this template through Smarty (with proper Smarty_Security in place) and then cleans the resulting HTML with HTMLPurifier.

Everything seems safe to me, but the users need functions so they can be used as Smarty modifiers. I can whitelist them one by one, but it would take a lot of effort and would be error-prone. I have only found a [blacklist - Exploitable PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions).

This is a somewhat [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056386/php-as-template-engine-stored-in-mysql-whitelist-functions), but there are no suitable answers (for my case).

Comment: Which functions do the users need? You have not shared that with your question, so probably you should. Additionally, what is the meaning of "exploitable" in your question. You have not written what you consider an exploit. Is this on the level of a three month old child fearing the world and therefore crying for mommy (one solution does it all) or is this more concrete?

Comment: I agree, I was maybe a bit vague in the question - however, [exploitable PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions) defines possible problems pretty well. I am basically looking for a function list that avoids them.

Comment: Take the superset of all functions in PHP and create the difference to the subset of the exploitable PHP functions. You then have negation of exploitable PHP functions which might be then the un-exploitable php functions. (if the defintion of exploitation can be clearly negated that way, I personally doubt it, but it's a free country)

Comment: This http://php.net/manual/en/aliases.php and this http://www.php.net/manual/en/indexes.functions.php might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, hakre - if noone can supply the precompiled list I will use this to make one.

Comment: As I tried to made more clear to you: **Your** list is what **you** think is secure. **Others** will think totally differently. And to add: **If anybody is posting you a list of "secure" functions, I won't trust him/her at all. The list might be for something completely different than you needs and I don't mean Smarty, I mean your site + app + customer + clients + users + designers**.

Comment: No need to shout, I understood you - I just don't agree with you. Given the use case I think it is pretty clear which functions should be considered safe and which not. I also think the use case is pretty common.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11191/discussion-between-hakre-and-johndodo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Smarty_Security` starts out with

```
$php_functions = array(
    'isset', 'empty',
    'count', 'sizeof',
    'in_array', 'is_array',
    'time',
    'nl2br',
);
```

adding the (presumably safe) operations for math and some more date and array stuff:

```
$php_functions = array(
    'isset', 'empty',
    'count', 'sizeof',
    'in_array', 'is_array', 'join', 'explode'
    'time', 'date', 'strtotime', 'strftime'
    'nl2br',
    'intval', 'floatval', 'rand', 'srand', 
    'log', 'log10', 'pi', 'pow', 'sqrt', 'exp', 
    'floor', 'ceil', 'round', 'min', 'max', 'abs',
    'sin', 'cos', 'tan', 'atan', 'atan2',
);
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am looking for a somewhat larger list - for instance array_shift, array_pop & similar should be in there too... There should be hundreds of entries. I will add your entries to my current list though. :)

Comment: I'm not sure you really want to be doing any `array_shift()` in a template. You could of course start with a reasonable set of allowed functions and add to the list once someone requires specific functions…

Comment: @rodneyrehm Is it reasonable to consider all "read-only" functions to be safe?

Comment: no. `file_get_contents()` is a readonly function, but could be abused to output a file you don't want public.

Comment: @rodneyrehm: I need to allow user to manipulate his variables (arrays, strings,...) as much as possible. I see no problem with `array_shift()` - do you? Note that user only sees the variables which are local to him.

Comment: I don't see any particular problem with `array_shift()`. I'm just wondering what you'd need it for in a template. While we're at arrays, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions/3697776#3697776 - don't allow anything that takes a callback

Comment: You want to *control* stuff in your *view*? *Does not sound like a good idea*

Comment: `time` is a function prone to information disclosure, I would not consider it secure.

Comment: @Dan Lee: actually the scenario is a bit more complicated than that. I must allow users to enter views that other users will see too. And I need to make sure the other users can do it safely (no XSS, no filesystem manipulation, no mail(),...).

Answer (score 2):

Did you see that great topic?
[Exploitable PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions)

So you can make "array_diff" between list of allowed functions and list of danger functions in your mind.

Comment: ... yet another useful article: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/disable-insecure-dangerous-php-functions

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned [Exploitable PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions) in the question. However, making an (automated) diff between all functions and (known) unsafe function does **not** produce a whitelist of safe functions - it is still just as good as a original blacklist (which is probably not complete). I would rather have an incomplete whitelist than a *supposedly* complete blacklist. :)