# php GET protection, do I really need it?

Tags: php

I have a php page.  It recieves a value for `id` via get.  2 simple questions:

1 - In my code this is used only once.  In an if statement like:

```
if ($_GET['id']==1){
Things here....
}
```

That is the only use of this passed id value.  Do I need to sanitize it or can I just leave it safely in the if statement without checking it?  Can hackers penetrate through this?

2 - Would I need to sanitize it if I had assigned it to a variable like:

```
$idid=$_GET['id'];
if ($idid==1){
Things here...
}
```

Like before this is the only use of this variable, it will not be used in echo or mysql etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to worry about sanitation, if the GET value is inserted in some potentially harmful place, i.e. `echo` (XSS), `mysql_query` (SQL Injection), `eval` (PHP Execution), `shell_exec` (Shell execution), ... (More extensive list at [Exploitable PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions))

Just checking for a value doesn't need any sanitation.

Comment: Warnings enabled: Not checking for an array's offset existance, will reveal it. --- What ''type of insertion into a potentially harmful place''-category would fall that under for your answer?

Comment: @hakre: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @hakre: Warnings aren't enabled on production servers ;) Furthermore: Why would it be a vulernability, if you would get an undefined offset xyz warning?

Comment: @nikic: Information exposure is used in penetration. Also see [Postel's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postel%27s_law).

Comment: @hakre: From the fact that an `id=abc` GET parameter is found in the URL it may easily be concluded, that this parameter will actually get used. No need to wait for a warning. And furthermore, as I already said, warnings aren't turned on on production servers, *never*.

Comment: @nikic: I see no URL in that question and I can only assume that Dave is following the practice you presuppose for production server configuration.

Comment: @hakre: See, this discussion is pointless, we don't know nothing about what or how he does. Maybe he even has the check for existence.

Comment: @nikic: :) -- You made me smile.

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need to sanitize it as it does nothing if it no other value than 1.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to sanitize it or can I just leave it safely in the if statement without checking it?

That depends on the level of quality you would like to achieve. It looks like that you access the `$_GET` array on a key that you don't test for existence.

This can trigger a notice like *"Notice: Undefined index: id"* which contains the filename as well.

Depending on server configuration, this message might be given to everybody requesting the website in question not providing the `id` URL query parameter.

Next to information offered to a potential attacker, spreading notices makes it harder for you to achieve a certain level of quality for your overall script, e.g. if you decide to turn notices and errors into feedback for maintaining and improving the script.

> Can hackers penetrate through this?

This information can be used to further penetrate your site then.

---

From the code you've shown you don't make further use of the variable / value and as far as I can say, I don't see an additional issue next to [information exposure](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/200.html).

It's always subject what you would like to achieve, security is nothing static. See [Defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), [Secure input and output handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_input_and_output_handling) and [Postel's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postel%27s_law).

Answer (score -2):

use === instead of == to determine the type of the entry.
In my opinion you don't need to do hard job to protect the input.
Only make sure that the input is really a number.

Comment: GET values are always strings or arrays. Checking against `=== 1` will always fail.

Comment: Thank you for thus useful information. So he need only to use intval function.

Comment: Or checking against `=== '1'` will do it.