# json_decode security

Tags: php, security, json

Is PHP's json_decode() secure as opposed to eval()? The eval() function can run code, but does json_decode() do that as well?

Answer (score 7):

Since [JSON](http://json.org/) can only represent data, `json_decode` will not execute php code.

However, just like any other function, the implementation of `json_decode` could be buggy and allow arbitrary (binary, not (only) php) code execution, for example with a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Due to the relatively simple and widely used code, this is unlikely, and there is nothing you can or should do in a php program to mitigate that.

Comment: +1 for bugs. PHP has not had a good security history, especially string handlers many of which have allowed arbitrary memory access.  See the information in the question Exploitable PHP functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions/3451100#answer-3697776. Certainly on PHP versions less than 5.2.9 a malicious attacker can cause a denial of service using json_decode(); see CVE 2009-1271 http://osvdb.org/52486

I would always try and perform at least a perfunctory form of validation yourself on completely untrusted data.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer.  The question is exactly whether `json_decode` might be buggy and allow arbitrary code execution.  You didn't answer the question.

Comment: D.W. Since the OP explicitely mentioned `eval` as a negative example (which is *not* intended to allow arbitrary code execution, just arbitrary *php* code execution), I don't think he considered bugs in the php implementation. Also, unless I'm totally misreading your comment, the second paragraph of this answer answers exactly "whether `json_decode` might be buggy and allow arbitrary code execution", with "yes, just like any other function". I'm puzzled as to what could be improved to clarify this answer. Can you give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

[eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) are two different functions, i don't know why you think they are similar. One evaluate a string as PHP code and the other decodes a JSON string. Nothing is executed when `json_decode` is run.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is confusing eval() in PHP with eval() in Javascript.  In Javascript eval() does what json_decode() does in PHP (turn JSON into an object) in addition to being able to evaluate and execute a string as code.