# How to get original data from base64Binary encoded data in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, base64

I am using Salesforce metadata API. I am geting a base64 data which contains a project manifest, a file named `package.xml`. How to get the `package.xml` file from this data.

Please see the encoded data below:

```
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
```

I am using base64_decode() method but I am getting output like below:

```
PKç2qA!unpackaged/objects/Contact.objectÕWßoÚ0~ç¯ˆò>œNÓ4M!¥T ñKGd’ñpj;´ùïë€@¨PV1žrŸÏçï¾»KŒ}ÿQc \˜5Ì»ºeÀ¼Ø'lÑ0»O_~˜÷NÍn%BÆÑpþ–Øtj†úÙÀðœÂ€/É°QÉ}tkä@BéGàô0[$xb6ól´ƒµ'¼JàÓ®ï˜Š,¼F´Ås :šr äl!CçÎ²ÔZþ¬9<'„Ãîˆ­]$ÇÞ2Ë©C”d<Ýºà¥-é WÑU^Ù£^IyN`¢°r©PY«SÂö'q¢ªsT¶ñ–T1ÒPþƒi¢ºX?…ù±À;GœP¹ÍakVC§Î;ƒÌ(Œ]–U%½!Z˜KÜCœczCÌTc„X€oô”ÿíðÊø¿¦#b.õ,Vípóþ¨Ž ¼<®gÌãèu^bY¤ÃØ‡'z^Ì||Kä—ä¦8‰>Ð%-záè]½¡Iàåhc7)mÅLbOŠ£½ªZyâÅ*x[Ý8RªKFv‚Æ÷[\Å4tÐR§+£Êå4·ÂeèãT¸!}0¼ÅÝ¯ØF0§5¸Í–[èŽÝÎcÓmJî9«€KuõrÔEB•ÉF©z®³îpÜNw2ë«ØåH©ø"î’7²ì"ýËÅì§ï®sŸ08]á~z•à¥‡…œ,?©²­q[•õqv½âöšw6m·Q[•·‘%nä™HÀ¬;þk7Óq€›±8- Êÿ€œÚPKFÓ äu8 PKç2qAunpackaged/package.xmlMŽÍ Â0„ï}Š»ÙX¤ˆ¤é¡àUúiºjÕ$¥YEßÞÚtO3ÃÇì¨âåîì‰]l‚ÏùRHÎÐÛP7þœóãa»XóB'joìÍœ‘õ´9¿µ€L+â)t… R)3+pH¦6d¸NXŠÞ-ÆQÞ¡«ú—ºžŒ%sðC¼q¨ËG¤àvÕ¿Ð…ð×¨¦õ:Í„T0»DÁ4Z'PKøäÞ¢æPKç2qAFÓ äu8 !unpackaged/objects/Contact.objectPKç2qAøäÞ¢æÄunpackaged/package.xmlPK“ª
```

Comment: That looks like a zip file possibly.

Comment: I think you get the correct decoded string. It looks like a compressed or encrypted file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: filename="my.zip"');
$s = "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";
$out = base64_decode($s);
print($out);
?>
```

And the browser downloads a working ZIP file that contains an .xml file.

If you want to process the contents of that ZIP file using PHP, you can enable the php_zip extension and check out this answer: [Unzip a file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889025/unzip-a-file-with-php)

Comment: Thank you. I tried the same code but it is downloading the php file itself, not a zip file

Comment: I am using Xampp localhost. the file name has extenssion as .php which is WinRAR ZIP archive (1.1 kB). After download when I double clicked on it, it is opening in editot with some special charectors loke PK [][][]

Comment: Download the file, rename it to .zip and open it with your unzipping software (or Windows built-in stuff). You can also add this to the PHP code to force the filename: `header('Content-disposition: filename="my.zip"');`