# linux: Convert spaces to underscores in filenames when unzipping the archive

Tags: php, linux, unzip

I am using exec "wrapper" for linux commands in PHP:

```
exec("unzip -oj tmp.zip -d tmp && rm tmp.zip");
```

Please tell me how can i convert spaces to underscores in filenames? Tnx,

Comment: You can do it all simply with PHP. [Extract the files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8889126/315306) and then rename those who contain a space in the name

Answer (score 2):

If you don'y mind using external utilities (as you're currently doing), you can use `rename` eg.

```
unzip -oj tmp.zip -d tmp && rename 's/\s/_/g' tmp/* && rm tmp.zip
```

Comment: Unfortunately, exec("unzip -soj tmp.zip -d tmp && rm tmp.zip"); does not work