# PHP Unzip very large file

Tags: php, linux, zip, freebsd, unzip

I have a zip file on the server.  It's 1.1gb made up of thousands of small files. I do not have shell or root access to the server and can only use ftp and create php files.. so far I have tried exec and shell exec but none worked.  The server is running free bsd. How can I unzip the file into the directory it is in?

Comment: Could you edit php.ini? I presume unzipping it in PHP would take a while and would cause a timeout.

Comment: All I have is ftp access into the web root directory, and php is pribably running as a limited user

Comment: If you can't change the timeout, I would think just unzipping locally and sending the files unzipped over FTP to the server over night would be the easiest solution. You need the sleep anyway, right? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I ended up modifying the code in this question to unzip the files.

[Unzip a file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889025/unzip-a-file-with-php?lq=1)

Answer (score 5):

For a pure PHP solution, try [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip) - this would not require you to install any PHP extensions or require shell access - you just need to write access to wherever you want to extract the files.

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = '/media/file.gz';

$unzipped_content = '';   
$zd = gzopen($filename, "r");
while ($zip_file = gzread($zd, 10000000)){
    $unzipped_content.= $zip_file;
}
gzclose($zd);

echo $unzipped_content;
```