# extracting a 30gb zip file with PHP

Tags: php

I have a requirement to unzip a file of around 30gb, each day. The zip holds around 500k individual files.
What is the best way to do this with php.
using the php zip library or exec ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Unzip very large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877888/php-unzip-very-large-file)

Comment: If your php is running on a linux system, just have a bash script unzip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complexe tasks that can be perform outside of PHP, it is sometimes better to just let the underlying Operating System do the heavy lifting. Do no reinvent the wheel.

I suggest that you use the `system()`method to execute a command that is available in the environment for extracting the 30GB file. It could be something like `system("unzip name_of_your_file.zip");`