# how to receive a chunked responses in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to receive a .zip file that's been chunked.

Here is my code :

```
// cUrl function
function send_request($url, $xml, $path, $save = TRUE){
    if($save == TRUE){
        $file = fopen($path, 'w'); // create a new file
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    if($save == TRUE){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); // save data direct to file
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); // close curl conn

    if($save == TRUE){
        fclose($file); // close the file
    }

    return $response;
}

$zip = send_request($url, $xml_product, './xml_product_response.zip', TRUE);
```

It seems to be working, the above code creates a file with lots of strange characters with headers.

I am now stuck, because I need to unzip and read the data from the file.

Can anyone help with that please?

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php): `CURLOPT_HEADER`: *TRUE to include the header in the output.*. Why is this enabled?

Comment: I can disable this, I am not a curl pro, its curl script I found on php manual

Comment: Disable it and check [Unzip a file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889025/unzip-a-file-with-php)

Comment: Nice one mate, worked great