# Unzip a zipped file using php

Tags: php, ftp, unzip, zip

Lets start by looking at what I am trying to accomplish.

I work for a web bureau, and we use almost the same CMS for every website. The CMS contains over 6000 files, so it takes a long time to upload. It is much faster to upload a zipped file, and then unzip it on the FTP server.

I browsed stackoverflow, and found this thread: [Unzip a file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889025/unzip-a-file-with-php)

This is fine. However, when i use this code:

```
<?php
// assuming file.zip is in the same directory as the executing script.
$file = 'concrete5.6.3.1-Dansk.zip';

// get the absolute path to $file
$path = pathinfo(realpath($file), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  // extract it to the path we determined above
  $zip->extractTo($path);
  $zip->close();
  echo "WOOT! $file extracted to $path";
} else {
  echo "Doh! I couldn't open $file";
}
?>
```

I get the following problem:

It unzips the entire .zip file. This is including the folder that was originally compressed. Which will create my index.php file, one directory too deep.

So instead of this:
    **www.hello.com/index.php**

It will come out as:
    **www.hello.com/folder/index.php**

**That was problem #1.**

**Here is problem #2:**

I work on mac, and when I unzip my zipped file, I get the annoying "_macosx" folder too.

Is there a way to fix both of these issues? :)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple method i am using

```
system('unzip assets_04_02_2015.zip');
```