# PHP Unzip Local File

Tags: php, unzip

Hi I need to download a zip file using ftp and then unzip it on local computer. I can download the file using ftp_get but I need help on unzipping it to specific location.

```
        $ftpServer = "server";
        $ftpUser = "user";
        $ftpPassword = "password";

        $ftp_server = $ftpServer;
        $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
        $ftp_login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftpUser, $ftpPassword ); 

        if(!$ftp_conn) 
            die("A connection to $ftpServer couldn't be established"); 
        else if(!$ftp_login) 
            die("Your login credentials were rejected"); 
        else
        {
            $file = "C:/files/downloads/FILE_NAME.ZIP";

            $server_file = "/FILE_NAME.ZIP"; 

            if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)) 
            {

                $zip = new ZipArchive;
                $res = $zip->open($file);

                if ($res === TRUE) 
                {
                  $zip->extractTo('C:/files/Feeds/');
                  $zip->close();
                }

                unlink($file);
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "There was a problem\n";
                $this->index();
            }
        }
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Have you looked at PHP's [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) at all?

Comment: Yes I did but some reason it is not working for me.

Comment: Well it might help if you showed some of your code, so we can look at what you're doing and try to work out what you're doing wrong..... if you don't show your code, all we can do is make wild guesses, which wastes our time and doesn't help you

Comment: Just added the code now. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889025/unzip-a-file-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code

**Unzip.php:-**

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('/sites/gallery.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/sites/New folder/test');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

For your reference see this link [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php)

Comment: I tired this and it fails but I know the path and file name are correct don't understand why it is failing.

Comment: Are zipping correctly.i mean zipping the files are ok?

Comment: Do one thing unzip FILE_NAME.ZIP this file in manually.

Comment: what error you got in your program?

Comment: It echos 'failed' but I dont understand why  because both file name and path are correct.

Comment: I just tried to unzip it manually using winrar and it is giving me error saying the archive is corrupt

Comment: If it fails, expand the failed section of the code to check for the error values that may be returned by [open()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php)

Comment: Figured it out I needed to use FTP_BINARY instead FTP_ASCII to download it and then ZipArchive to unzip it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ZipArchive class for this

```
$archive = new ZipArchive;
if ($archive->open('my_zip_fil.zip') === TRUE) {
    $archive->extractTo('destination/dir');
    $archive->close();
}
```

[ZipArchive documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)

Comment: Hi thank you for your help but I tried to use ziparchive and it wont extract the file for some reason or giving me any errors.