# How do I exclude files from zip download?

Tags: php, file, download, zip

Currently I use this code to download a zip file:

```
<?php
    $weborder = $_POST['weborder'];
    $printlocation = $_POST['print'];

$file = 'z:\Backup\\'.$printlocation.'\\'.$weborder.'.zip';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo ":(";
}
?>
```

The zip file contains 4 files. The problem that I am having right now is that 3 files shouldnt be downloaded. I was wondering if there is a simple way to select which files dont get downloaded.

Comment: A zip file is one file, so unless you unzip the file first.. then you can't

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way for selective zip download.
You should *repack you zip archive* with files you want to serve for download.

---

Here are few related question just to not duplicate them here:

- [Unzip a file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889025/unzip-a-file-with-php)
- [Download multiple files as ZIP in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php)

What you need to do is to *extract files you want to serve* for downloading.
You can accomplish this by using "selective" unzip ...

```php
$zip->extractTo('/some/dir/', ['number_one.file', 'some_other.file']); // or single file in your case
```

... and then pack them, and serve newly created zip archive with files you wanted.

More info on how to do this you can find in related links above.

---

**UPD:** And I would mention that it is **not a good practice** to use user input directly in your scripts. It is potential security breach.

Comment: Do you have any example for me on how to achieve that?