# Ziparchive unable to open zip file only in PHP

Tags: php, bash, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to unzip a file using PHP [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class but when I try:

```
$file = '/path/to/zip/file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open($file, ZipArchive::CHECKCONS);
```

The result is `ZipArchive::ER_INCONS` (Zip archive inconsistent)

Now, I've been able to open the zip file on my desktop (Windows 7) as well as using the `bash` command line tool `unzip` on the same box where the PHP application is running (Ubuntu 12.04). I am even able to unzip the file with in PHP using `exec('unzip', $file);`.

I have checked permissions for the cache folder and the zip file and the webserver has both read and write permission.
I am able to open other zip file in the same directory with PHP's ZipArchive class.

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but the zip file I'm trying to open contains two zip files.

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unzip a file with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889025/unzip-a-file-with-php)

Comment: Can you post the file you are trying to unzip?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot because of sensitive information in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the file was being upload as ASCII, and I changed it to upload as binary.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! How much time I have spend on changing the unzipping script, while it was actually the FTP file upload. How did you find it out?