# Woocommerce Product downloadable files

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I have three files in a WooCommerce product which users can download after purchasing the product. How can they download all three files at once? Right now it is setup as they have to download it one by one. I don't how to use WooCommerce bulk download, it creates an .zip file. I need something simple where users can download all the files at once.

Comment: You have mentioned that Woocommerce creates a .ZIP File. I am not exactly sure - but somehow dig into the process of creation of the Woocommerce ZIP file and then unzip the created file. Use the following answer to understand how to unzip a file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8889126/6653215

Comment: I was trying to say that there is a plugin called Woocommerce Bulk download [ https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bulk-download/ ] which converts all the files into a .Zip folder but i don't that i need which the user should be able to download all the files without zip file.