# execute php page that unzip a file (manipulate files)

Tags: php, apache, redhat

Im using a local (rhel 8) server to unzip a file using php (solution proposed in : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8889126/9583635)

```
<?php
// assuming file.zip is in the same directory as the executing script.
$file = 'temperatures.zip';

// get the absolute path to $file
$path = pathinfo(realpath($file), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file);
if ($res === TRUE) {
  // extract it to the path we determined above
  $zip->extractTo($path);
  $zip->close();
  echo "Success! $file extracted to $path";
} else {
  echo "Failled! I couldn't open $file";
}
?>
```

The problem is:

- when I execute this code on the server using:
  `php /var/www/html/unzip.php`
  it works fine (success message) and I find the extracted file in the same directory.
- but when I use browser (http://192.168.1.5/unzip.php) the success message is printed but I can't find the unziped file in this directory.

note: I tried using wamp server and it works, so the problem may be in the server.

Comment: `and I find the extracted file in the same directory` Same directory as what

Comment: as the zipped file. The working directory is : /var/www/html/

Comment: Does your webserver account `www`? Have access to the directory that the zip file is on?

Comment: I gave my useraccount all privileges, using `chmod -R 777  /var/www/html/` command. the `ls -l` command show : `drwxrwxrwx. 2 toto toto 100 Apr 19 17:55 html` - @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way all the php line codes that were manipulating files wasen't taking affect. I solved this by allowing the Apache user (`apache` in rhel) to create files in the directory. This can be done by making Apache the owner of the directory running this cmd:

`sudo chown apache /var/www/html/`