# PHP ZipArchive gives Invalid or uninitialized Zip object error on extraction

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I'm having trouble extracting file some files from zip using ZipArchive

Here is my code

```
$pp_saved_zip_archive = "$extract_path/archive.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($pp_saved_zip_archive, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->extractTo($previews_path);
$zip->close();
```

I get two errors/warnings in this code

`PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in ...`

`PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in ...`

If I check for `$res` variable it returns `19`, which is weird, it should be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`

My paths are correct, so it's not a path problem. This is done behind WordPress, I've tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `ABSPATH` to no avail. I also tried with different zip files, still no luck.

Answer (score -2):

```
$result = $zipArchive->open("The archive you want to open");
if ($result === TRUE) {
    $zipArchive ->extractTo("my_dir");
    $zipArchive ->close();
    // Do something else on success
} else {
    // Do something on error
}
```

Try this
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8889073/5717344

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).