# PHP preg_replace, split or match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-split

I need to parse a string and replace a specific format for tv show names that don't fit my normal format of my media player's queue.

Some examples

Show.Name.**2x01**.HDTV.x264 should be Show.Name.**S02E01**.HDTV.x264
Show.Name.**10x05**.HDTV.XviD should be Show.Name.**S10E05**.HDTV.XviD

After the show name, there may be 1 or 2 digits before the x, I want the output to always be an S with two digits so add a leading zero if needed. After the x it should always be an E with two digits.

I looked through the manual pages for the preg_replace, split and match functions but couldn't quite figure out what I should do here. I can match the part of the string I want with `/\dx\d{2}/` so I was thinking first check if the string has that pattern, then try and figure out how to split the parts out of the match but I didn't get anywhere.

I work best with examples, so if you can point me in the right direction with one that would be great. My only test area right now is a PHP 4 install, so please no PHP 5 specific directions, once I understand whats happening I can probably update it later for PHP 5 if needed :)

Comment: `please no PHP 5 specific directions` -- Why not? Why are you using an ancient PHP version? Why don't you want to upgrade to a more recent version?

Comment: My media server runs its own php4 back end which I am not looking to mess with right now. That's an issue for another time =/

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code, please. No one is going to install PHP 4 and do the work for you.

Comment: I wouldn't ask anyone to, the various code examples provided all seem to function to the goal so its exactly what I asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach as a solution using [`#sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) using **PHP4** and below.

```
$text = preg_replace('/([0-9]{1,2})x([0-9]{2})/ie',
                     'sprintf("S%02dE%02d", $1, $2)', $text);
```

**Note**: The use of the `e` modifier is depreciated as of **PHP5.5**, so use `preg_replace_callback()`

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/([0-9]{1,2})x([0-9]{2})/', 
      function($m) {
         return sprintf("S%02dE%02d", $m[1], $m[2]);
      }, $text);
```

Output

```
Show.Name.S02E01.HDTV.x264
Show.Name.S10E05.HDTV.XviD
```

See [working demo](https://eval.in/57536)

Comment: This definitely seems to be the shortest route to the goal, one function with all the required aspects, thanks for the additional solution :)

Comment: You should avoid the use of the `e` modifier -- [it's deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Check [this awesome post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions). Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) instead.

Answer (score 1):

preg_replace is the function you are looking function.

You have to write a regex pattern that picks correct place.

```
  <?php
  $replaced_data = preg_replace("~([0-9]{2})x([0-9]{2})~s", "S$1E$2", $data);
  $replaced_data = preg_replace("~S([1-9]{1})E~s", "S0$1E", $replaced_data);
  ?>
```

Sorry I could not test it but it should work.

Comment: There are no letters in your regex, so the `i` modifier is not needed. You also do not use any `.` metacharacter in the regex, which means that the `s` modifier is not needed either. Also, the replacing does not handle leading `0`s, which the questioner clearly stated they would like to see.

Comment: I modified the pattern.

Comment: Why do you use the `s` modifier?! It only has an effect if you use the `.` metacharacter. You do not use it in your regexes. It is not needed. Also, `[1-9]{1}` is *exactly the same* as `[1-9]`. There is no need to explicitly say that there is only one of something; it is implied.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: You forget the `x` letter.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yeah, I missed that. Using `[xX]` should suffice, though. I have never seen a capital X in the episode/season part of a TV show file name, however, but they could occur so better to be on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I've looked up the different parts of the solution and have a much better understanding of whats going on now, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An other way using the `preg_replace_callback()` function:

```
$subject = <<<'LOD'
Show.Name.2x01.HDTV.x264 should be Show.Name.S02E01.HDTV.x264
Show.Name.10x05.HDTV.XviD should be Show.Name.S10E05.HDTV.XviD
LOD;

$pattern = '~([0-9]++)x([0-9]++)~i';
$callback = function ($match) {
    return sprintf("S%02sE%02s", $match[1], $match[2]);
};

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $subject);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks I hadn't previously seen this function, definitely worth looking into further :)