# What is the cost and the benefit of greatly restricting functions and classes with disable_functions and disable_classes?

Tags: php, performance, web-services, security

I have performed some research and began building a complete list of PHP 5's builtin functions as documented on the project site.

What is the **performance** cost of leveraging `disable_functions` and/or `disable_classes`?

How do these global settings work?

Note that I came across a very valuable [list of exploitable functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions/3697776#3697776) and [the RIPS scanner](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rips-scanner/).

However, it does seem more complete to actually block all functions and classes that aren't used in the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disable_functions` removes function handlers (pointers to actual function implementations) from a PHP function list and replaces it with a handler to a dummy function which shows the warning instead:

```
Warning: system() has been disabled for security reasons in Command line code on line 1
```

It is just a processing time for PHP (every time it is invoked - a script is accessed) to do this replacement.

I'm not quite sure about `disable_classes` as I've never used it.

**However, please DO NOT consider this a security feature - [check this](http://www.php.net/security-note.php) out for more info.**

Any bug in PHP (overflows, use-after-free and similar) will allow a potential attacker to tamper with the process memory and fix the function handlers to point to the correct function handlers which are still in memory - **this results into re-enabling the disabled functions**.

Always separate in shared hosting environments. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25409315/2645631) to another similar question.