# PHP: Return all user-defined functions

Tags: php

I have PHP shell and I want user to be able to call functions directly. I got it done. But then I found out that user can call even pre-defined functions like unlink and more. I think this is security hole so I want to restrict callable functions to only those which I have defined, e.g.:calling unlink wont work.

Comment: Nice question! You'll need to write a wrapper program to restrict the commands that can be sent to `php`. E.g. using C#, if you're targeting Windows.

Comment: [`get_defined_functions()["user"]`](http://php.net/get_defined_functions) just returns yours. A simple whitelist would make more sense however.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions

Comment: php shell means `php -a` or a php cli application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of define functions with

```
get_defined_functions();
```

It will return an assoc array with user defined and internal functions. You can use that information to decide whether a functions is user defined or internal. ([manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-defined-functions.php))

Comment: And how would he restrict non-user-functions from being executed by `php`?

Comment: Can say only when I know his code. Looks like OP need to wrap function calls

Comment: His code is irrelevant. He's using `php`, e.g. the PHP shell.

Comment: Do you mean `php -a`? I don't see this information in the question

Comment: Yes. The question says "I have PHP shell".

Comment: A php cli application isn't a *php shell*. If he has a php cli application then he could create a whitelist using information returned by `get_defined_functions()['user']`.. So it should be useful. isn't it?

Comment: The PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) defines `php -a` as an "interactive shell". I'm curious myself now as to whether this could be done without a wrapper program. Let's see if the OP responds with more info!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable functions using the [`disable_functions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) INI setting (in your php.ini file).

For example:

```
disable_functions=unlink,fopen,file_get_contents [and so on...]
```