# Upper or Lower Case Issue using get_file_contents php

Tags: php

I am using a PHP GET method to grab a file name that then is placed in a get_file_contents command. If it is possible, I would like to ignore letter case so that my URL's are cleaner.

For instance, example.com/file.php?n=File-Name will work but example.com/file.php?n=file-name will not work using the code below. I feel like this should be easy but I'm coming up dry. Any thoughts?

```
$file = $_GET['n'];
$file_content = file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: *nix or windows platform?

Comment: It's an Apache server

Comment: i understand it's an apache but on what platform is it running on? Windows ignores case while you have to know the exact filename on *nix (and also mac) systems..

Comment: Oh. I'm using Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: :) and the apache webserver is running on your mac or somewhere else? It depends on where the files are and what platform is running there..

Comment: Sorry, I'm dumb. The server is on a linux VM. I haven't had coffee yet.

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase all your filenames and use:

```
file_get_contents(strtolower($file));
```

(I hope you're aware of some of the [risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions) involved in using this.)

Comment: There is an iOS app that is uploading these files for me, so I cannot have them changed to lowercase. I was hoping to figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux filesystem is case sensitive. If you want to do case insensitive matching against files that already exist on the user's machine, your only option is to obtain a directory listing and do case-insensitive comparison.

But you don't explain where the download URLs come from. If you already know the correct filenames and you want to generate prettier URLs, you can keep a list of the true pathnames and look them up when you receive a case-normalized one in a URL (you could even rename them completely, obfuscate, etc.)