# Renaming an upload file and display it

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, file-rename

every book and article that i've read recommend that we should rename upload file for security purpose. let say i have a code like this:

```
if (!isset($error)) {

$file = $_FILES['images'];
$real_pic_name = $_FILES['images']['name'];;
// Create a tmp_name for the file:
$tmp_name = sha1($file['name']) . uniqid('',true);

// Move the file to its proper folder but add _tmp, just in case:
$dest = PDFS_DIR . $tmp_name . '_tmp';

if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $dest)) {

//insert into database with a prepared statement
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (real_pic_name, tmp_name, dateAdded) VALUES (:real_pic_name, :tmp_pic_name, now())');
$stmt->execute(array(
':real_pic_name' => $real_pic_name,
':tmp_pic_name' => $tmp_name
));

// Rename the temporary file:
$original =  PDFS_DIR . $tmp_name . '_tmp';
$dest =  PDFS_DIR . $tmp_name;
rename($original, $dest);

// Print a message:
echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><h3>The file has been uploaded!</h3></div>';

} else {
trigger_error('The file could not be moved.');
unlink ($file['tmp_name']);
}

}
```

the problem is i'm confuse about what is a better way to display the images files because i don't think that renaming the file isn't good idea. I'm thinking about add some extra column in my mysql to save the extension and then maybe put in in session to call the images file, i don't know. can anyone give me some solution or sample code that can help me since most of tutorial that i've read only explain about uploading and renaming file name and not the file extension neither display the upload files. thanks.

Comment: putting in session the file name insted that fetching it from db doesn't change anything. You can store the real name of the file and save the content of the file to db, maybe this can help

Comment: yeah i already save it, now i'm just confuse how to display the file that already renamed and ext that changed too.

Comment: If you accept only images from users you can check for img resolution. PHP has a function for that.

Comment: yeah i understand that i should validate user input i already done it. now the problem is about displaying the uploaded files which the file and the extension is changed. i think rename the file again isn't good idea.

Comment: mmm, for me you need to check if it's a good file, If good you do not need to do something for showing. Example you can check on upload for extension, mime type and first byte header, this way you can be a litte more sure

Comment: i already check all from check extension, filetype, mimetype, and else, and now the last thing to do to secure my upload files is maybe this. because i know that hacker can manipulate files mime or type and put a code inside it. by renaming this at least it make difficult for hacker to know which file he's being uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename;
```

Comment: the problem is not about in renaming files but how to display it after it was renamed (in my case the file become exactly 63 characters long file name with _tmp as extension. i want to know is it possible to display it without have to rename it again