# Case (in)sensitive Replace for str_ireplace for search results

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

I have a list of items. I want to use them in search terms. Say the list is:

- Hello, World!
- The World is not Enough
- Around the world in 80 days.
- WAR of the WORLDS

Now, if I am searching for the keyword `world` (notice all are in small letters), I am giving this function.

```
preg_replace(/world/, '<span class="label label-search-results">$0</span>', $item);
```

Where the `$item` is each line, the output is:

> **Warning:** `preg_replace()` [[function.preg-replace]](http://about:blank): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in **/myfile.php** on line XX.

If I use `str_ireplace()`, I don't know the original case of the found text. It would be something like:

```
str_ireplace("world", '<span class="label label-search-results">world</span>', $item);
```

And that results in all the `world`, `World` and `WORLD` being in lower case. Any ideas on how to **preserve** the case after replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the perfect use case for [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), just use it like this:

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/" . preg_quote($_GET["q"], "/")  . "/i", function($m){
    return "<span class='label label-search-results'>" . $m[0] . "</span>";
}, $item);
```

Comment: I don't want to make everything in lower case. I wanna preserve the case. If not, I can use `str_ireplace()`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ah then just remove the `strtolower()` call in the callback function

Comment: I am using it from `$_GET["q"]`. So, how do I do that?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Just change `$item` with `$_GET["q"]` and save the return value of `preg_replace_callback()` into a variable as you want it

Comment: I don't wanna use the `/world/i`. Coz that's in `$_GET["q"]`. Can you edit the answer please? `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ah, so you mean the search sting is in `$_GET["q"]` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76299/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-rizier123).

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(world)/i', '<span class="label label-search-results">$1</span>', $item);
```

Try with the flag `i` for case-insensitivity.

Comment: I am using it from `$_GET["q"]`. So, how do I do that?

Comment: @PraveenKumar don't. never allow the user to control your regular expression, as it can lead to remote code execution.

Comment: Exactly... So this is a search term, which is `mysqli_real_escape_string()`'ed... So lemme know. `:)`

Comment: Notice: preg_replace (with /e modifier)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions is exploitable only. Not with i modifier