# Security for social networking website

Tags: php, mysql, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What security issues should I look out for in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165040/what-security-issues-should-i-look-out-for-in-php)

How to protect my site(social networking) from being hacked?just suggest some methods that are in common?

i am using php for scripting & mysql for database and i am using CodeIgniter(php framework).

if you know some good tutorial or ebooks then provide me some link

-Abhijeet

Comment: This doesn't seem programming-related.  If any solutions involve any sort of programming, that would be on-topic.

Comment: @David Thornley: many solutions involve writing secure code, does that count?

Comment: @Mchl:  Asking how to write secure code in a given environment is on-topic.  Asking a question that could possibly wind up with writing code isn't.  It's usually best to avoid writing code when you need a secure solution:  the bad guys can't break into anything that isn't there, and you're going to make a lot of obscure mistakes that experienced secure programmers won't.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/php-security