# PHP:MySQL - Security Threats

Tags: php, mysql, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What security issues should I look out for in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165040/what-security-issues-should-i-look-out-for-in-php)

- what are the **SECURITY THREATS** while using PHP connected with MySQL
- what **STEPS** should be followed\insured to maximize security

Comment: -1 Damn dude search before you post and ask better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should at least properly quote your data to avoid injection. Google PHP and Mysql Injection for more information on this. Also see: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

especially note example2 which explaines injection.

Comment: Or use prepared statements, which means it'll be done correctly for you.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, SQL injection is the most common attack. But also have to be sure you don't use a superuser or any other database role that has too much permissions, to connect with your database. Make sure you create a role that has the bare minimum permissions to function, and use this role in your PHP script.

You could also use stored procedures and/or views to revoke direct access to tables and data.

And whatever you do, make sure you use strong passwords and only store hashes of these passwords.

Do not trust input, all input is evil.

Answer (score 0):

Number one issue is usually user input, especially when using a database. Make sure the user can **never** input anything that can harm your site - whether it's executable PHP (say you're using [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) for some reason), or [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).