# Checking if a variable is an integer in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
    $page = $_GET['p'];

    if($page == "")
    {
        $page = 1;
    }
    if(is_int($page) == false)
    {
        setcookie("error", "Invalid page.", time()+3600);
        header("location:somethingwentwrong.php");
        die();
    }
    //else continue with code
```

which I am going to use for looking at different "pages" of a database (results 1-10, 11-20, etc). I can't seem to get the is_int() function to work correctly, however. Putting "1" into the url (noobs.php?p=1) gives me the invalid page error, as well as something like "asdf".

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Using [`is_numeric()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.is-numeric.php) for checking if a variable is an integer is a bad idea. This function will return `TRUE` for `3.14` for example. It's not the expected behavior.

To do this correctly, you can use one of these options:

Considering this variables array :

```
$variables = [
    "TEST -1" => -1,
    "TEST 0" => 0,
    "TEST 1" => 42,
    "TEST 2" => 4.2,
    "TEST 3" => .42,
    "TEST 4" => 42.,
    "TEST 5" => "42",
    "TEST 6" => "a42",
    "TEST 7" => "42a",
    "TEST 8" => 0x24,
    "TEST 9" => 1337e0
];
```

#### The first option (FILTER_VALIDATE_INT way) :

```
# Check if your variable is an integer
if ( filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false ) {
  echo "Your variable is not an integer";
}
```

Output :

```
TEST -1: -1 (type:integer) Your variable is an integer ✔
TEST 0 : 0 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 1 : 42 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 2 : 4.2 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 3 : 0.42 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 4 : 42 (type:double) is an integer ✔
TEST 5 : 42 (type:string) is an integer ✔
TEST 6 : a42 (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 7 : 42a (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 8 : 36 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 9 : 1337 (type:double) is an integer ✔
```

#### The second option (CASTING COMPARISON way) :

```
# Check if your variable is an integer
if ( strval($variable) !== strval(intval($variable)) ) {
  echo "Your variable is not an integer";
}
```

Output :

```
TEST -1: -1 (type:integer) Your variable is an integer ✔
TEST 0 : 0 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 1 : 42 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 2 : 4.2 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 3 : 0.42 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 4 : 42 (type:double) is an integer ✔
TEST 5 : 42 (type:string) is an integer ✔
TEST 6 : a42 (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 7 : 42a (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 8 : 36 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 9 : 1337 (type:double) is an integer ✔
```

#### The third option (CTYPE_DIGIT way) (positive numbers and 0 only):

```
# Check if your variable is an integer
if ( ! ctype_digit(strval($variable)) ) {
  echo "Your variable is not an integer";
}
```

Output :

```
TEST -1: -1 (type:integer) # Your variable is not an integer ✘
TEST 0 : 0 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 1 : 42 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 2 : 4.2 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 3 : 0.42 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 4 : 42 (type:double) is an integer ✔
TEST 5 : 42 (type:string) is an integer ✔
TEST 6 : a42 (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 7 : 42a (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 8 : 36 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 9 : 1337 (type:double) is an integer ✔
```

#### The fourth option (REGEX way) :

```
# Check if your variable is an integer
if ( ! preg_match('/^-?\d+$/', $variable) ) {
  echo "Your variable is not an integer";
}
```

Output :

```
TEST -1: -1 (type:integer) Your variable is an integer ✔
TEST 0 : 0 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 1 : 42 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 2 : 4.2 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 3 : 0.42 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 4 : 42 (type:double) is an integer ✔
TEST 5 : 42 (type:string) is an integer ✔
TEST 6 : a42 (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 7 : 42a (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 8 : 36 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 9 : 1337 (type:double) is an integer ✔
```

Comment: Pay attention with FILTER_VALIDATE_INT (your preferred way) 0 returns false!

Comment: Use filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false instead.

Comment: I think there is a ! missing at `if(filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false) echo "its not an integer` ,right?

Comment: or the text should be changed to ` it is an iteger`

Comment: Great answer, I've been burned by trying is_numeric had to change it, hopefully your comments will save some people trouble ...

Comment: Validation is always very difficult to cater to all examples. In the above example, using "FILTER_VALIDATE_INT" does not return as an integer the number: "09" perhaps because "09" is not an integer? Well, yes and no....in dates, "09" is a formatting issue rather than a numeric vs string issue.  So validating a number as a date, could lead to some trouble when using: "fliter_validate_int" which sees "09" as a string.  Using REGEX solved the problem and returned: 09 as an integer (regardless of its type casting).

Comment: It would be good if you added these cases:

'00'
'01'
'12.00' 

Different implementations will return different answers.  I'd suggest that all three are integers, in the common man sense of the word...

Comment: The 'CTYPE_DIGIT way' and 'REGEX way' both fail for negative integers. The 'REGEX way' can be fixed by checking if there is a leading negative sign (`-?`), but I don't believe that `ctype_digit` can be used in a concise way to check for negative integers. Also, the posted code cannot produce the corresponding outputs.

Comment: TYPO in first solution:
```if ( filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false ) { echo "Your variable is not an integer"; }``` must be ```if ( filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false ) { echo "Your variable is not an integer"; }```!

Comment: What about `is_int()`?

Comment: This answer could be improved by directly answering the question about `is_int()` . Starting the answer by saying that `is_numeric` is a bad idea is confusing.

Comment: Be aware of integers as '2.0' (string), for that numbers all this methods returns false.

Answer (score 36):

All `$_GET` parameters have a string datatype, therefore, `is_int` will always return false.

You can see this by calling [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump):

```
var_dump($_GET['p']); // string(2) "54"
```

Using [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) will provide the desired result (mind you, that allows values such as: `0x24`).

Comment: Warning: this will return true for more than just ints, use one of the other solutions below.

Answer (score 28):

When the browser sends `p` in the querystring, it is received as a string, not an int.  `is_int()` will therefore always return false.

Instead try `is_numeric()` or [`ctype_digit()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

Answer (score 20):

Just for kicks, I tested out a few of the mentioned methods, plus one I've used as my go to solution for years when I know my input is a positive number or string equivalent.

I tested this with 125,000 iterations, with each iteration passing in the same set of variable types and values.

**Method 1:** `is_int($value) || ctype_digit($value)`
**Method 2:** `(string)(int)$value == (string)$value`
**Method 3:** `strval(intval($value)) === strval($value)`
**Method 4:** `ctype_digit(strval($value))`
**Method 5:** `filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== FALSE`
**Method 6:** `is_int($value) || ctype_digit($value) || (is_string($value) && $value[0] === '-' && filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== FALSE)`

**Method 1:** 0.0552167892456
**Method 2:** 0.126773834229
**Method 3:** 0.143012046814
**Method 4:** 0.0979189872742
**Method 5:** 0.112988948822
**Method 6:** 0.0858821868896

(I didn't even test the regex, I mean, seriously... regex for this?)

***Things to note:***
Method 4 always returns false for negative numbers (negative integer or string equivalent), so is a good method to consistently detect that a value is a positive integer.
Method 1 returns true for a negative integer, but false for a string equivalent of a negative integer, so don't use this method unless you are certain your input will never contain a negative number in string or integer form, and that if it does, your process won't break from this behavior.

**Conclusions**
So it seems that if you are certain that your input will not include a negative number, then it is almost twice as fast to use `is_int` and `ctype_digit` to validate that you have an integer. Using Method 1 with a fallback to method 5 when the variable is a string and the first character is a dash is the next fastest (especially when a majority of the input is actual integers or positive numbers in a string). All in all, if you need solid consistency, and you have no idea what the mix of data is coming in, and you must handle negatives in a consistent fashion, `filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== FALSE` wins.

*Code used to get the output above:*

```
$u = "-10";
$v = "0";
$w = 0;
$x = "5";
$y = "5c";
$z = 1.44;

function is_int1($value){
    return (is_int($value) || ctype_digit($value));
}

function is_int2($value) {
    return ((string)(int)$value == (string)$value);
}

function is_int3($value) {
    return (strval(intval($value)) === strval($value));
}

function is_int4($value) {
    return (ctype_digit(strval($value)));
}

function is_int5($value) {
    return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== FALSE;
}

function is_int6($value){
    return (is_int($value) || ctype_digit($value) || (is_string($value) && $value[0] === '-' && filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) !== FALSE);
}

$start = microtime(TRUE);
for ($i=0; $i < 125000; $i++) {
  is_int1($u);
  is_int1($v);
  is_int1($w);
  is_int1($x);
  is_int1($y);
  is_int1($z);
}
$stop = microtime(TRUE);
$start2 = microtime(TRUE);
for ($j=0; $j < 125000; $j++) {
  is_int2($u);
  is_int2($v);
  is_int2($w);
  is_int2($x);
  is_int2($y);
  is_int2($z);
}
$stop2 = microtime(TRUE);
$start3 = microtime(TRUE);
for ($k=0; $k < 125000; $k++) {
  is_int3($u);
  is_int3($v);
  is_int3($w);
  is_int3($x);
  is_int3($y);
  is_int3($z);
}
$stop3 = microtime(TRUE);
$start4 = microtime(TRUE);
for ($l=0; $l < 125000; $l++) {
  is_int4($u);
  is_int4($v);
  is_int4($w);
  is_int4($x);
  is_int4($y);
  is_int4($z);
}
$stop4 = microtime(TRUE); 

$start5 = microtime(TRUE);
for ($m=0; $m < 125000; $m++) {
  is_int5($u);
  is_int5($v);
  is_int5($w);
  is_int5($x);
  is_int5($y);
  is_int5($z);
}
$stop5 = microtime(TRUE); 

$start6 = microtime(TRUE);
for ($n=0; $n < 125000; $n++) {
  is_int6($u);
  is_int6($v);
  is_int6($w);
  is_int6($x);
  is_int6($y);
  is_int6($z);
}
$stop6 = microtime(TRUE); 

$time = $stop - $start;  
$time2 = $stop2 - $start2;  
$time3 = $stop3 - $start3;  
$time4 = $stop4 - $start4;  
$time5 = $stop5 - $start5;  
$time6 = $stop6 - $start6;  
print "**Method 1:** $time <br>";
print "**Method 2:** $time2 <br>";
print "**Method 3:** $time3 <br>";
print "**Method 4:** $time4 <br>";  
print "**Method 5:** $time5 <br>";  
print "**Method 6:** $time6 <br>";
```

Comment: This comparison makes sense if you wish to optimize for performance, but that is not always the case. Many people will find the regex method `preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $value)` easier to understand, and it performs as well as some of the other methods here.

Comment: OP may prefer a solution that only allows _positive integers_ , such as 1, 2, 3. Allowing negative integers and zeros could be problematic. Speed might not matter.

Answer (score 9):

/!\ Best anwser is not correct, is_numeric() returns true for integer AND all numeric forms like "9.1"

For integer only you can use the unfriendly preg_match('/^\d+$/', $var) or the explicit and 2 times faster comparison :

```
if ((int) $var == $var) {
    // $var is an integer
}
```

PS: i know this is an old post but still the third in google looking for "php is integer"

Comment: This is wrong, because this condition will be true even when e.g. $var="9". It should be if ((int) $var === $var).
$a == $b Equal TRUE if $a is equal to $b after type juggling.
$a === $b Identical TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

Comment: notice that `(int) $var` will return zero if the string can't be made into a number, so:

`(int) 'banana' === 0`

Comment: Downvoted as comments reveal this answer is not right.

Comment: @IgnacioSegura so is it safe if used after a validator like `if (is_numeric($var) && ((int) $var == $var)) {...}`?

Comment: @GuneyOzsan what you suggest sounds right, but to be honest, I stopped coding in PHP two years ago and I forgot a lot of stuff. Sorry I could not be more helpful.

Comment: @IgnacioSegura no worries. I wanted to keep discussion alive because that part was still open. Someone else may comment later on. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

doctormad's solution is not correct. try this:

```
$var = '1a';
if ((int) $var == $var) {
    var_dump("$var is an integer, really?");
}
```

this prints

> 1a is an integer, really?"

use [filter_var()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with *FILTER_VALIDATE_INT* argument

```
$data = Array('0', '1', '1a', '1.1', '1e', '0x24', PHP_INT_MAX+1);
array_walk($data, function ($num){
$is_int = filter_var($num, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($is_int === false)
var_dump("$num is not int");
});
```

this prints

```
1a is not int 
1.1 is not int
1e is not int
0x24 is not int
9.2233720368548E+18 is not int
```

Comment: I liked your solution...accepts 0, yet denies non-integer characters.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem just now!

You can use the `filter_input()` function with `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` and `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE` to filter only integer values out of the `$_GET` variable. Works pretty accurately! :)

Check out my question here: [How to check whether a variable in $_GET Array is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194205/how-to-check-whether-a-variable-in-get-array-is-an-integer)

Answer (score 3):

When i start reading it i did notice that you guys forgot about abvious think like type of to check if we have int, string, null or Boolean. 
So i think `gettype()` should be as 1st answer.
Explain:
So if we have `$test = [1,w2,3.45,sasd];` we start test it

```
foreach ($test as $value) {
        $check = gettype($value);
        if($check == 'integer'){
            echo "This var is int\r\n";
        }
        if($check != 'integer'){
            echo "This var is {$check}\r\n";
        }
}
```

And output:

```
> This var is int 
> This var is string 
> This var is double 
> This var is string
```

I think this is easiest way to check if our var is int, string, double or Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Values `$_GET` are always strings – that's what GET paramters come as. Therefore, `is_int($_GET[...])` is always false.

You can test if a string consists only of digits(i.e. could be interpreted as a number) with [**is_numeric**](http://php.net/is_numeric).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a casting operator to convert it to an integer:

```
$page = (int) $_GET['p'];

if($page == "")
{
    $page = 1;
}
if(empty($page) || !$page)
{
    setcookie("error", "Invalid page.", time()+3600);
    header("location:somethingwentwrong.php");
    die();
}
//else continue with code
```

Comment: Well, if you cast it to an integer first, then `is_int` and `is_numeric` will always return true...

Comment: yes, on top of that this will turn values like e.g. 14.9999 into 14

Answer (score 1):

```
$page = (isset($_GET['p']) ? (int)$_GET['p'] : 1);
if ($page > 0)
{
  ...
}
```

Try casting and checking if it's a number initially.

Comment: The call to `is_int()` here is redundant. The variable `$page` will always be an integer here, due to the previous line of code.

Comment: @netcoder/@Hammerite: Touche, forgot that a cast will supply the default value. Should be checking if `>0`. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the correct function should look as following:

```
    public function checkIfValueIsInt($value): bool
{
    if (is_bool($value)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (0 === filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

given set of tests is validated correctly using it:

```
        [
            true,
            false,
        ],
        [
            false,
            false,
        ],
        [
            'false',
            false,
        ],
        [
            'true',
            false,
        ],
        [
            'some random string',
            false,
        ],
        [
            [],
            false,
        ],
        [
            ['some string', 1],
            false,
        ],
        [
            (object) [],
            false,
        ],
        [
            2.222,
            false,
        ],
        [
            rand(0, 99999),
            true,
        ],
        [
            1,
            true,
        ],
        [
            0,
            true,
        ],
        [
            -1,
            true,
        ],
```

the reason I added is_bool check is that

> true

value is handle incorrectly by:

```
0 === filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check int and float types:

```
private function isInteger(mixed $val): bool
{
    if (!is_scalar($val) || is_bool($val)) {
        return false;
    }

    return !$this->isFloat($val) && preg_match('~^((?:\+|-)?[0-9]+)$~', $val) === 1;
}

private function isFloat(mixed $val): bool
{
    if (!is_scalar($val) || is_bool($val)) {
        return false;
    }

    return gettype($val) === "double" || preg_match("/^([+-]*\\d+)*\\.(\\d+)*$/", $val) === 1;
}
```

}