# How to check whether a variable in $_GET Array is an integer?

Tags: php, get, validation

I have a page like so:

> `http://sitename/gallery.php?page=2`

It has pagination links at the bottom by which we can browse. Everytime the page numbers are clicked, it would send a GET request with parameters **page=1** or **page=2** and so on ...

When I store these values to `$page` from teh `$_GET` variable, it is a string value. I can convert it to an integer using `(int)` like this:

```
if(!empty($_GET['page'])){
       $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
       echo "Page Number: ".$page;
}
```

But how can I make sure that the value passed is an ***integer only*** and not other crap?

Comment: didnt you find this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416763/checking-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-php

Comment: Actually no. Thanks for pointing that out! :) I wasn't aware of the `var_dump()`

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to make sure the value is an int? If you are always casting to an int then nothing else can get through... the only reason I can think of would be if you wanted to show an error page when anything else comes through, or if you are planning to also send other data types (other than `int`) as the value of `page`? Other than that you don't need to check it's type... Not that I'm against asking the question - just questioning the use in this case... knowledge for knowledge's sake is always good :)

Comment: It's just that I don't want people to pass in random things like for example: **wrwh!@67** - OR something malicious.

Comment: @maxxon15 - Yes as I thought, in this case, if you only ever access or use the `$page` variable after you have cast to an int - you need not worry about malicious content... because anything that isn't numeric will be cast to 0. `echo (int) '//*&73...\\made_up_nonsense...!'; #will echo 0`. It's good to be thinking in this regard however ;) you will not believe the number of scripts out there that allow anything to be passed in and used in scary ways...

Comment: Yeah... But still, I try to maintain this, since they say its always a  good practice to do so. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using filters:

```
if (null !== ($page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE))) {
    // $page is now an integer
}
```

This also checks whether the variable appears in the query string at the same time. If you want to differentiate between missing and invalid you have to leave off the last argument to `filter_input()`:

```
$page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
// $page can be null (not present), false (present but not valid) or a valid integer
```

Comment: Works! Thanks man! :)

Btw, this could have been achieved by `filter_var()` function too. Right?

Comment: @maxxon15 I prefer using `filter_input()` if I know that the parameter should come from `INPUT_GET` - otherwise I use `filter_var()` :)

Comment: That clears the use case. :) Thanks for helping out a noobie here!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` filter on it, and check the return value.

Comment: Thanks! :D How could I forget the filters! Silly me!

Answer (score 2):

Use [is_numeric()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

`is_int()` will not work because GET parameters are always string.

Answer (score 1):

I've left a few comments here and there. Thanks to weak typing, functions like `empty` and `isset` tend to be unreliable. The quickest way to check if a parameter is an int or not IMO would be this:

```
if (array_key_exists('page',$_GET) && ($_GET['page'] == (int) $_GET['page']))
```

Casting to int and then compare the respective values will return true only when `$_GET['page']` *is* a valid int. If you want to use strict type comparison for some reason (some do), you could double cast:

```
if (array_key_exists('page',$_GET) && ($_GET['page'] === (string)((int) $_GET['page'])))
```

But in this particular case, I can't really see why you would want to do that

Comment: Why not? Is it not a good practice to always check the authenticity of the data that's passed?

Btw, I already used the `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` as shown in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12194343/432720

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by _why not?_. When I said _I can't see why you want to do that_, I was referring to the double cast: casting to an int, and back to a string again is, IMO, one operation too many in this example

Comment: Oooh! I thought you meant casting to `(int)` or even choosing this option would be unnecessary! :P Nevermind.
But yeah... I agree. That'd really be too much.

Comment: @maxxon15: Unless, of course, `$_GET['page']` could be an empty string (`''`), in which case `('' == (int)'') === true` while `'' == (string)((int)'') === false`... sheesh, loose typing, gotta love it :s

Answer (score 1):

this is a way how to check parameter if it is intetger or not.

```
if (is_int((int) $_GET['user_id']) && (int) $_GET['user_id'] != 0) {
    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `is_int` won't help, probably. All incoming parameters (including $_GET and $_POST) are parsed as strings by PHP. The `is_int` function checks the datatype, not the value. `ctype_digit` checks for only digits though:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && ctype_digit($_GET['page']){
   $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
   echo "Page Number: ".$page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_GET['page']) and is_numeric($_GET['page'])){
       $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
       echo "Page Number: ".$page;
}
```

[is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check with

```
isNAN($_GET['something']);//is_numeric($_GET['something'])
```

it returns a boolean value(true,flase)....if its true then it is not an integer,if false its an integer.

Comment: Returns true for floats, too: so `page=12.7548754` would be valid?

Comment: My dear brother,is there any page number with float number...???and you given the page numbers as "page" rite..??

Comment: It's a GET variable, there's nothing stopping the user from messing with the url parameters, and passing a float. That's, I think, why the op wants to check if the value of the parameter is an int, rather then a string or float

Comment: I have also the same doubt Elias

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && (($get_page_filtered = filter_var($_GET['page'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) !== FALSE) {
  $get_page_int = $get_page_filtered;
}
```

@see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41868665/6758130