# php7 how to check, that only int values in html form

Tags: php, if-statement

this code accepts numbers, e.g. 13.5, 15.6 etc...
I need that checked if this is a number only int, e.g. 13, 14 ... etc.

```
if (is_numeric($r_haslo) == false) {
    $wszystko_ok = false;
    $_SESSION['e_haslo'] = "<i class=\"fas fa-user-times\"></i> Podaj tylko cyfry!";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a variable in $\_GET Array is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194205/how-to-check-whether-a-variable-in-get-array-is-an-integer)

Answer (score 0):

if it has to be an integer and integer only this is how I like to do it.

```
if (is_numeric($r_haslo) == false || ((int)$r_haslo != $r_haslo)) {
    //is an integer
    $wszystko_ok = false;
    $_SESSION['e_haslo'] = "<i class=\"fas fa-user-times\"></i> Podaj tylko cyfry!";
}
```

With the updated code above, this now makes sure that `$r_haslo` is not a number first, and if it is a number, that the number is not an int. So if it's not a number or not an int then it will save the warning to the session.

This way if I send 23 and "23" both are true. 
If I send 23 and "23" to `is_int()` function only 23 will be true.

If you never send string input then `is_int()` is probably the better way to go.

## Update

```
if (strpos($mystring, ".") || is_numeric($r_haslo) == false || ((int)$r_haslo != $r_haslo)) 
{
    //is an integer
    $wszystko_ok = false;
    $_SESSION['e_haslo'] = "<i class=\"fas fa-user-times\"></i> Podaj tylko cyfry!";
}
```

The updated code above will also make sure that there is not a '.' in the input.

**Note** 
if the value is being passed as a number, PHP will automatically convert 12.0 and 12. to 12. if the value is being passed as a string, the `srtpos()` method will catch it.

Comment: I would like it to be false

Comment: okay, this is working but i need, that if i press: `12.0` or `12.` that this still does not return the true.  so how do I block the possibility of entering a dot?

Answer (score 0):

When you say this code accepts, I'll interpret that as you are taking user input by way of a HTTP POST or GET.

The following will only assign and cast to an integer if the posted string contains digits (an unsigned integer within) otherwise it will be assigned null.

```
<?php
$id = isset($_POST['id']) && ctype_digit($_POST['id'])
    ? (int) $_POST['id']
    : null;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can us is_int() to check.

```
if (is_int($r_haslo) == false) {
    $wszystko_ok = false;
    $_SESSION['e_haslo'] = "<i class=\"fas fa-user-times\"></i> Podaj tylko cyfry!";
}
```

Comment: `is_int()` is false for a string even if it contains the characters of an integer.