# php check to see if variable is integer

Tags: php, html, validation

Is there a nicer way to do this?

```
if( $_POST['id'] != (integer)$_POST['id'] )
    echo 'not a integer';
```

I've tried

```
if( !is_int($_POST['id']) )
```

But `is_int()` doesn't work for some reason.

My form looks like this

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="id">
</form>
```

I've researched `is_int()`, and it seems that if

```
is_int('23'); // would return false (not what I want)
is_int(23);   // would return true
```

I've also tried `is_numeric()`

```
is_numeric('23'); // return true
is_numeric(23); // return true
is_numeric('23.3'); // also returns true (not what I want)
```

<strike>it seems that the only way to do this is:</strike> [this is a bad way, do not do it, see note below]

```
if( '23' == (integer)'23' ) // return true
if( 23 == (integer)23 ) // return true
if( 23.3 == (integer)23.3 ) // return false
if( '23.3' == (integer)'23.3') // return false
```

But is there a function to do the above ?

---

Just to clarify, I want the following results

```
23     // return true
'23'   // return true
22.3   // return false
'23.3' // return false
```

---

**Note: I just figured out my previous solution that I presented will return true for all strings. (thanks redreggae)**

```
$var = 'hello';
if( $var != (integer)$var )
    echo 'not a integer';

// will return true! So this doesn't work either.
```

---

This is not a duplicate of [Checking if a variable is an integer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416763), because my requirements/definitions of integer is different than theres.

Comment: Try RegEXP. `preg_match('/^[\d]*$/',$variable)!==FALSE`

Comment: Why do you need to "validate"? Cannot you just filter values? So: $input = (int)$_POST['id'] . This will give you a 100% safe integer (or 0 in case of issues), and it is much easier to handle...

Comment: @Qualcuno I was thinking about that, but I want to notify the user that they didn't type in a correct number and not change it for them.

Comment: how about var_dump($_POST["id"]),this will tell you the datatype;

Comment: Why? Suppose he/she types "aaa", it will become 0 and you will refuse it the same way as you'd refuse the input 0. (because it's an id, so I suppose it will be > 0). You will just tell your users "wrong input", no need to detail it further!

Comment: @Qualcuno suppose they type in `23.3` and meant to type in `233`... casting it will truncate it to `23` ... which would be bad.

Comment: @Arian This is an edge case. Just add some JS on the input field to refuse every non-numeric digit. Server-side checks should be meant more as security measures: for correcting user inputs you could use JS without problems, in my opinion

Comment: yes..I've clarified that in my edit. "php" == 0 is `true`!

Comment: @redreggae Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Glad that somebody had already added this post to [web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235746/php-check-to-see-if-variable-is-integer) for preservation. I was going to do it otherwise..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a variable is an integer in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416763/checking-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-php)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

try [ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

```
if (!ctype_digit($_POST['id'])) {
    // contains non numeric characters
}
```

Note: It will only work with `string` types. So you have to cast to `string` your normal variables:

```
$var = 42;
$is_digit = ctype_digit((string)$var);
```

Also note: It doesn't work with negative integers. If you need this you'll have to go with regex. I found [this](http://www.askingbox.de/frage/php-negative-zahlen-pruefen-und-ctype-digit) for example:

EDIT: Thanks to LajosVeres, I've added the D modifier. So `123\n` is not valid.

```
if (preg_match("/^-?[1-9][0-9]*$/D", $_POST['id'])) {
    echo 'String is a positive or negative integer.';
}
```

More: The simple test with casting will not work since "php" == 0 is `true` and "0" === 0 is `false`!
See [types comparisons table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for that.

```
$var = 'php';
var_dump($var != (int)$var); // false

$var = '0';
var_dump($var !== (int)$var); // true
```

Comment: `$integer = 42;
ctype_digit($integer);` will return false

Comment: This is a good solution unless OP needs to support negative integers.

Comment: yes..if you check it with "normal" variable and not $_GET or $_POST than first cast to `string`. `$is_digit = ctype_digit((string)42);`

Comment: @aaron That is correct a string would need to be input.  Luckily in case of `$_POST` values, they are always strings.

Comment: @MikeBrant you're right..negative integers won't work. Than you have to check with regex. Something like `if (!preg_match("/^-?[1-9][0-9]*$/", $_POST['id']))`

Comment: @aaron thanks for letting me know it doesn't work in that case. This is a great solution for $_POST, but there is still no substitute for `$var == (integer)$var`, besides `preg_match` which isn't simpler

Comment: I don't think there's a need to use those unknown functions in a simple case like this.

Comment: @GeoffreyHuck Well, they're not unknown once you've used them... I think `ctype_digit` should be used much more often than `is_numeric`, which has a more memorable name but is rarely actually the test you want to perform.

Comment: In case it matters, both `ctype_digit` and this particular regex will return true for strings containing values way too big for an int.

Comment: @cHao I cannot verify that. Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: @cHao I've tested it with really big integer strings and it works. So there seems to be no casting to integer involved?!

Comment: @redreggae: Currently?  None.  I don't need an interpreter to see this, though.  `ctype_digit('1234567890123456789012345678901234567890')` will return `true`.  That means it's lying about whether the string would be a valid int.

Comment: @cHao because it is an integer..so where is the problem? `ctype_digit('1234567890123456789012345678901234567890a')` will return `false` which is correct.

Comment: @cHao ok got you..I think this is beyond the question. If you're doing your math with BCMath it doesn't matter. It really depends on what the OP is doing with his integers.

Comment: You need the D modifier to the preg_match. And it doesn't accept the 0 to number.

Comment: @LajosVeres hmm..the D modifier makes no difference for me. can you give an example? And I kinda like it that it doesn't accept leading zeros.

Comment: Sorry but without line breaks it is not really nice... The main idea is that trailing \n will be accepted without D.

$ php5 -r 'preg_match("/^-?[1-9][0-9]*$/","123\n") && print "accepted\n";'
accepted
$ php5 -r 'preg_match("/^-?[1-9][0-9]*$/D","123\n") && print "accepted\n";'
$

Answer (score 17):

try `filter_var` function

```
filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

use:

```
if(filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) { 
    //Doing somethings...

}
```

Answer (score 9):

In PHP `$_POST` values are always text (`string` type).

You can force a variable into the integer type like this:

```
$int_id = (int)$_POST['id'];
```

That will work if you are certain that `$_POST['id']` *should be* an integer. But if you want to make absolutely sure that it contains only numbers from `0` to `9` and no other signs or symbols use:

```
if( ctype_digit( $_POST['id'] ) )
{
  $int_id = (int)$_POST['id'];
}
```

Comment: Not true: `$_POST` can be array.

Answer (score 3):

Using `is_numeric()` for checking if a variable is an integer is a bad idea.
This function will send `TRUE` for `3.14` for example. It's not the expected behavior

To do this correctly, you can use one of these options :

Considering this variables array :

```
$variables = [
    "TEST 0" => 0,
    "TEST 1" => 42,
    "TEST 2" => 4.2,
    "TEST 3" => .42,
    "TEST 4" => 42.,
    "TEST 5" => "42",
    "TEST 6" => "a42",
    "TEST 7" => "42a",
    "TEST 8" => 0x24,
    "TEST 9" => 1337e0
];
```

## The first option (FILTER_VALIDATE_INT Way) :

```
# Check if your variable is an integer
if( ! filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ){
  echo "Your variable is not an integer";
}
```

Output :

```
TEST 0 : 0 (type:integer) is not an integer ✘
TEST 1 : 42 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 2 : 4.2 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 3 : 0.42 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 4 : 42 (type:double) is an integer ✔
TEST 5 : 42 (type:string) is an integer ✔
TEST 6 : a42 (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 7 : 42a (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 8 : 36 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 9 : 1337 (type:double) is an integer ✔
```

## The second option (CASTING COMPARISON Way) :

```
# Check if your variable is an integer
if ( strval($variable) != strval(intval($variable)) ) {
  echo "Your variable is not an integer";
}
```

Output :

```
TEST 0 : 0 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 1 : 42 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 2 : 4.2 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 3 : 0.42 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 4 : 42 (type:double) is an integer ✔
TEST 5 : 42 (type:string) is an integer ✔
TEST 6 : a42 (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 7 : 42a (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 8 : 36 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 9 : 1337 (type:double) is an integer ✔
```

## The third option (CTYPE_DIGIT Way) :

```
# Check if your variable is an integer
if( ! ctype_digit(strval($variable)) ){
  echo "Your variable is not an integer";
}
```

Output :

```
TEST 0 : 0 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 1 : 42 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 2 : 4.2 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 3 : 0.42 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 4 : 42 (type:double) is an integer ✔
TEST 5 : 42 (type:string) is an integer ✔
TEST 6 : a42 (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 7 : 42a (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 8 : 36 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 9 : 1337 (type:double) is an integer ✔
```

## The fourth option (REGEX Way) :

```
# Check if your variable is an integer
if( ! preg_match('/^\d+$/', $variable) ){
  echo "Your variable is not an integer";
}
```

Output :

```
TEST 0 : 0 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 1 : 42 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 2 : 4.2 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 3 : 0.42 (type:double) is not an integer ✘
TEST 4 : 42 (type:double) is an integer ✔
TEST 5 : 42 (type:string) is an integer ✔
TEST 6 : a42 (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 7 : 42a (type:string) is not an integer ✘
TEST 8 : 36 (type:integer) is an integer ✔
TEST 9 : 1337 (type:double) is an integer ✔
```

Answer (score 2):

Check it out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php - it validates if string contains only digits, so be sure not to pass an int to that function as it will most likely return false; However all values coming from `$_POST` are always strings so you are safe. Also it will not validate negative number such as `-18` since `-` is not a digit, but you can always do `ctype_digit(ltrim($number, '-'))`

`is_int` checks the variable **type** which in your case is `string`; it would be the same as `(integer)$v === $v` as `==` does some real obscure things in order to compare two variables of a different type; you should always use `===` unless you want mess like `"0af5gbd" == 0` to return true

Also, keep in mind that `ctype_digit` will not tell you if the string can be actually converted to a valid `int` since maximum integer value is `PHP_INT_MAX`; If your value is bigger than that, you will get `PHP_INT_MAX` anyway.

Comment: nice idea with `ltrim($number, '-')`..but remember that `---123` will work in this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/^\d+$/D',$variable) //edit
```

Answer (score 2):

if you know it is a string variable (like post o get values), you can use:

```
function is_really_integer($var) {
  return $var == (string)(integer)$var;
}
```

Comment: this is what I do and it's very fast

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer using ctype_digit is correct, however you can make life easier using a function. This will covert the variable to a string, so you don't have to:

```
function is_num($x){
    if(!is_string($x)){
        $x=(string)$x;
    }
    if(ctype_digit($x)){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (is_num(56)) {
    // its a number
}

if (is_num('56')) {
    // its a number
}
```

If you want to accept decimals too, use this:

```
function is_num($x){
    if(!is_string($x)){
        $x=(string)$x;
    }    
    if (strpos($x,'.')!==false) {      
        if(substr_count($x,'.')>1||strpos($x,'.')<1||strpos($x,'.')>=strlen($x)){
            return false;    
        }
        $x=str_replace('.','',$x);    
    }
    if(ctype_digit($x)){
        return true;
    }  
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **filter_var** but be careful it's return bool.

In case you have string '0' => you will get false

Right way to use:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false) { 
    // Doing somethings...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following, universal function to check all types:

```
function is_digit($mixed) {
    if(is_int($mixed)) {
        return true;
    } elseif(is_string($mixed)) {
        return ctype_digit($mixed);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
is_int($val)||ctype_digit($val)
```

Note than this catch only positive integer strings

Answer (score 0):

[is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) is perfectly working there is not need of extra code

or you can check using [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Comment: If you read my question, you'd see why `is_int` and `is_numeric` don't give me the right values.