# Using is_numeric() and typecasting to (int)

Tags: php

OK, I've read some guides, and I'm still a bit confused as to the purpose of this.

I've come across a bit of code in a project that I've picked up from a previous developer, which has items like this all across it:

```
if (is_numeric($var) && ((int)$var == $var){
```

What is the purpose of typecasting $var to int in the second check? The whole thing is going to evaluate false if $var is not numeric, or at least a string that can evaluate to numeric. And even if $var is a string and not a number, the second check is going to evaluate to true, again, if the string can evaluate to a number.

Wouldn't it make more sense to just use is_numeric() and leave it at that?

Comment: `is_numeric` doesn't mean it's an integer. It just means it's a number.

Comment: Geez, I wasn't paying attention. Thanks for the answers, anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an attempt to solve a common problem, because of the limitations of certain seemingly obvious strategies:

- `is_numeric($var)` returns true for numbers in lots of formats, such as `'1.5e10'`
- `(int)$var == $var` checks that converting the number to an `int` results in a value that compares back to the original, but for non-numeric strings PHP tries to be clever, so `'1a' == 1`

If both checks succeed, it's an integer, congratulations.

However, if what you want is a positive integer, `ctype_digit((string)$var)`, which simply checks if the string contains nothing but digits, is a much more compact alternative.

See also: [php check to see if variable is integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235746/php-check-to-see-if-variable-is-integer)

Answer (score 0):

as said  in the comment, `is_numeric` just checks if the variable is a number. The second check `(int)$var == $var` checks to see if the integer value of the number is equal to the number. In other words, if the number is an integer.

If the number was a real number, `is_numeric` returns true . But in the second check the real number is casted to an integer. so 3.14 becomes 3, and `3==3.14` fails.

The second check returns true only if the number is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

As cole already pointed out, the `is_numeric` function can tell you whether the particular `$var` is a numeric value, which may or may not be a integer.

The `(int)$var == $var` is checking whether it is a integer or not. You could also use [is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) for this.