# Check if array can be converted to int then convert laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an array collection that I converted to array using toArray(). Which changes all items to a string. I want to check every item that can be converted to an integer/decimal. The array looks like this

```
['first_name'] => 'Jake',
['last_name'] => 'Doe',
['age'] => '13', (Change this to an integer/decimal)
['address'] => 'Ivory Street'
['allowance'] => '3000' (Change this to an integer/decimal)
```

I'm using Laravel/Livewire

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a variable is an integer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416763/checking-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-php)

Comment: You can use Model Casting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways to convert `int` or `float`. This is the logic :

```
$data = collect([
    'first_name' => 'Jake',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'age' => '13',
    'address' => 'Ivory Street',
    'allowance' => '3000',
    'float?' => '0.6'
])
->map(function($item){
    return (is_numeric($item))
        ? ($item == (int) $item) ? (int) $item : (float) $item
        : $item;
})
->toArray();

dd($data);
```

Result :

```
array:6 [
  "first_name" => "Jake"
  "last_name" => "Doe"
  "age" => 13
  "address" => "Ivory Street"
  "allowance" => 3000
  "float?" => 0.6
]
```

Comment: This is correct but now I'm facing a  problem when I map an array when it has a value of null, it changes it to 0.00

Comment: No issue for `null` value. Are you sure?

Comment: My bad it works, but I had a problem in displaying it in my blade file. Which I also resolved, this is the answer.